# Why is hibernate composite object not complete after persist?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, composite, persist

I am supporting a CRUD legacy application with relatively simple data model. In order to boost the performance by enabling lazy loading, I switched from a Hibernate session per DB query (openSession / closeSession surrounding each query) to a Hibernate transaction per HTTP request done by a Tomcat filter:

```
public class HibernateSessionRequestFilter implements Filter {
  public void doFilter ... {
    HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

As far as data reading is concern all works fine.

But there is a problem when composite object gets persisted and then rendered in the same request (transaction). The object mapping is like

```
<class name="xxx.data.ReportDescription" table="report_descriptions">
 ...
 <many-to-one name="job" class="xxx.data.Job" column="jobId"/>
```

The persist code is:

```
Session session = HibernateSession.currrentSession();
session.persist(reportDescription);
LOGGER.info("report PERSISTED: " + reportDescription.getJob());
```

The "job PERSISTED" LOGGER output shows that the Job object has only valid id and all its other fields are nulls, which is not correct - the existing Job object that is pointed by the new reportDescription object has not null values in all its fields.

If I continue by loading the reportDescription newly within the same transaction using:

```
ReportDescription fetchedReportDescription = 
    ReportDescriptionHelper.getReportDescription(reportDescription.getId());
LOGGER.info("report FETCHED: " + fetchedReportDescription);
```

I get again the composite Job object with valid id and null values in the other fields.

If I close the transaction and start a new one, all works fine:

```
HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
fetchedReportDescription = 
    ReportDescriptionHelper.getReportDescription(reportDescription.getId());
LOGGER.info("report FETCHED: " + fetchedReportDescription);
```

Logically, on the next HTTP request all data is consistent.

I have two solutions in mind, and I don't like both of them as they are just workarounds:

- load the composite fields explicitly (by code) after persist()
- commit and begin a new transaction after each persist()

Any ideas why I get such behavior? Any ideas for a nice solution?

Thank you in advance!